# PHP script status bar

Tags: javascript, php, progress, blockui

I have created a php script that submits a query and downloads the results in a CSV. I have created a bootstrap button where users can click to download the file. Some of the reports take longer to create and I wanted to show the user some sort of status that the script is running in the background.

I tried something simple like [BlockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#overview) from inside the PHP script. Using `echo '<script type="text/javascript">$.blockUI();</script>';` in the beginning of the script and `echo '<script type="text/javascript">$.unblockUI();</script>';` at the end but it didn't work.

Can someone help? I don't need a progress bar or anything fancy. I just need to show some type of status while the php script is running.

**HTML**:

```
...
<td class="pull-right"><a type="button" href="report1_download_csv.php" class="btn">Download</a></td>
...
```

**PHP**:

```
<?php
/* Set up and execute the query. */
$sql = "SELECT 
FROM   TABLE ";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) )  {
 foreach($row AS $key => $value){
        $pos = strpos($value, '"');
        if ($pos !== false) {
            $value = str_replace('"', '\"', $value);
        }
        $out .= '"'.$value.'",';
    }
    $out .= "\n";
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt($results);
sqlsrv_close($conn);
// Output to browser with the CSV mime type
header("Content-type: text/x-csv");
$date = date('m-d-Y-His');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Report1_{$date}_UTC.csv");
echo "Column1, Column2\n";
echo $out;
?>
```

Comment: When you click a link to visit another page (that's basically what you're doing here) the current site unloads. It may not always be instantaneous but it happens. The only way to show a status report is to keep current page running. For that, you need to make your download happen with AJAX or inside a `<iframe>`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. When I click on the button it doesn't refresh the page or anything it just downloads the file. `header("Content-Disposition: attachment;`. Using ajax is possible but from researching saving a file proves a little more difficult. I've seen workarounds using blobs but just wanted to see if there was something easier.

Answer (score 0):

use ajax to send request to server to do operation then show a spinner or any thing else untill server give you response.